# Why doesn't memory id change when there are no references to it?

Tags: python

```
>>> x = 5
>>> id(x)
40186104
>>> x += 6
>>> id(x)
40185960
>>> z = 5
>>> id(z)
40186104
```

Python deletes all objects once there are no more references to it.

Here when `x` is bound to `11`, there are no more references to `5`. So I suppose it is deleted. Then why does its id remain the same after reallocation?

The other possibility is that `5` is not deleted at all. If so, then why?

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Comment: In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.

Answer (score -3):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) notes

> Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

Comment: Although that's true, it isn't what's going on here.